# JSON String with Arrays iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

My APP gets a JSON string from a api call JSON string has **objects** and a **array** in it. This is what i have done so far but i couldn't get the values from it . advice me please and I'm new to iOS .This is my JSON String :

```
{
   "Id":"0d95a9f6-c763-4a31-ac6c-e22be9832c83",
   "Name":"john",
   "ProjectName":"project1",
   "StartDate":"\/Date(1447200000000)\/",
   "Documents":        
   [{
       "Id":"2222a","Name":"book1","ContentType":"application/pdf"
    }, 
   {
       "Id":"3718e","Name":"Toolbox","ContentType":"application/fillform"
   }]
}
```

Code

```
NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mysite/API/Assignments?"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

assignArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i=0; i<json.count; i++) {
    NSString *aID=[[json objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Id"];
    NSString *uName=[[json objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSString *pName=[[json objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"ProjectName"];

    //[self initwithUserID:uID userName:uName proName:pName];
  // [self retrieveAssignmentDetails:aID];
    AssignmentsJson *assignment=[[AssignmentsJson alloc]initwithassignID:aID userName:uName proName:pName];
    [assignArray addObject:assignment];
```

Comment: I think you got dictionary not array...so just simply try `[json objectForKey:@"Id"];`

Comment: A side note, you should not use `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]` to get the data from a network resource. It will block the GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your `json` is not array so parse like following

```
NSString *aID = json[@"Id"];
NSString *uName = json[@"Name"];
NSString *pName = json[@"ProjectName"];
NSString *startDate = json[@"StartDate"];

NSArray *documents = json[@"Documents"];
for (NSDictionary *item in documents) {
    NSString *itemID = item[@"Id"];
    NSString *itemName = item[@"Name"];
    NSString *itemContentType = item[@"ContentType"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . Works Perfect !

Answer (score 0):

Your `Json` Object is `NSDictionary`. so you can directly get data using `valueForKey`

```
NSDictionary *json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSString *aID = json[@"Id"];
NSString *uName = json[@"Name"];
NSString *pName = json[@"ProjectName"];
```

for `Id`,`Name` and `ContentType` is inside your array object within your NSDictionary object.

so you can get those values accessing array index.

```
NSArray *arr = json[@"Documents"];
for (int i=0; i<arr.count; i++) {
    NSString *aID=[[arr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Id"];
    NSString *uName=[[arr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSString *cType=[[arr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"ContentType"];
}
```

You should learn `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` Structure first. it will help you in future. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Works Perfect !

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by following way.

Your `Json` is in `NSDictionary` format.

```
 NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite/API/Assignments?"]];
    NSDictionary * dicResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];


    if(dicResponse){
        NSString * strID = [dicResponse valueForKey:@"Id"];
        NSString * strName = [dicResponse valueForKey:@"Name"];
        NSString * strProjectName = [dicResponse valueForKey:@"ProjectName"];
        NSString * strDate = [dicResponse valueForKey:@"StartDate"];
        NSArray * arrDocuments = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dicResponse valueForKey:@"Documents"]];

        for (int i=0; i< arrDocuments.count; i++) {

            NSString * ID=[[arrDocuments objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"Id"];
            NSString * Name=[[arrDocuments objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"Name"];
            NSString * Type=[[arrDocuments objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"ContentType"];
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks much better :)